# high-side circuit works?

Tags: mosfet, switches, high-side

What is the aim of 100ohm resistor between the micro-controller pin and the gate of the N-channel MOSFET?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The 100 Ohm resistor on the gate of the N-Channel MOSFET is there to stop any potential ringing. Ringing is caused by gate capacitance in series with the inductance of the track/wire.

The 10k resistor is just a pull-up resistor to keep the gate of the P-Channel MOSFET high. Or so I assume as you haven't actually labelled the nodes of the P-Channel. Once the MCU pin goes high, the N-Channel MOSFET turns on, which pulls the gate of the P-Channel MOSFET low, turning it on and allowing current to flow through it.

Comment: Is it worth explaining the finite turn-off time as a function of the pull-up value?

Comment: @AaronD I'd say not. Looking at the nature of the question, it's clearly a beginner level question. So they deserve answers that don't overcomplicate things in my opinion. It's likely not going to be of much use at this level